# Android Play store certificate fail

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

I am trying to upload an APK from my second computer and it fails with the error below. I copied the release key from Comp. 1 to Comp. 2 and ran the same build scripts. Yet it fails? I bet I am missing something real simple...

```
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: a:hex:key ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: other:hex:key]
```

I'm developing with ionic build btw.

---

Edit:
this is how I sign it on the two machines, the keystore file is identical.
Is it something else I should change?

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ./play-release-key.keystore platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk AppName
```

Answer (score 0):

When you generate your signed APK(s), you need to make sure that you use the same keystore file for each app.

What's happening here is that you are using a different keystore file to generate your APK then you did with the previous version of your app, so you get an error.

---

If you're wondering, the reason your keystore has to be the same is to prove that it's from the same person and is "authentic". This extract from the [developer docs for Signing Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) may help:

> When you sign an APK, the signing tool attaches the public-key certificate to the APK. The public-key certificate serves as as a **"fingerprint" that uniquely associates the APK to you and your corresponding private key**. This helps Android ensure that any future updates to your APK are **authentic and come from the original author**.

Furthermore...

> You must use the **same certificate** throughout the lifespan of your app in order for users to be able to install new versions as updates to the app.